# parsing xml from sdcard

Tags: android

Guys, I have a problem that I want to parse a xml file from sdcard but I don't want to parse it from accessing particular nodes. I want to get all data through any one of the technique as SAX,DOM, or PullParser but I don't want to access particular node by its name. How will I  do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own SAX or DOM parser that is able to understand the xml file that you need to parse.

You can follow this [tutorial](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/02/sample-saxparser-in-android.html) on how to implement a SAX parser for Android which is more memory efficient than the DOM parser since it does not need to store the DOM tree in memory and is event based.